# How can I local gltf loader three js to show in github server in my repo

Tags: javascript, github, three.js, gltf, repo

when I run code on my vs app it work but when it run on github it warn error 404 aborted, I found a documentation that about this problem but I don't understand 
link my work on github:
https://panupatspyksw.github.io/3dMonkey/

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, we can see Suzanne on your github page. Work on chrome.